# How do I Iteratively set the @property decorator for every value in a list?

Tags: python

I have a class that is mainly used to store calculation made on other attributes of the class. However, I want to do multiple calculations where n differs and set every calculation as a new attribute of the class.

The code below shows an example of setting the attribute for a single value.

```py
@dataclass
class A:
   
   @property
   def set_property_5(self):
      return self.method(5)

   def method(self, n):
      return n * 2
```

What I want to do is the following (This doesn't work, but I think this illustrates my purpose well):

```py
@dataclass
class A:
   
   for n in [5, 10, 15]:

      @property
      def set_property_n(self):
         return self.method(n)

   def method(self, n):
      return n * 2
```

How should I tackle this problem? and what is the best practice in setting the attributes for every value of n in the example below?

Comment: Can you say more about why you want to do it this way?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's questionable if you should do this but you can:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class A:
   
   def method(self, n):
      return n * 2

for n in [5, 10, 15]:
    setattr(A, f"set_property_{n}", property(lambda self, _n=n: self.method(_n)))

#Test:
print(A().set_property_10)
```

An alternative may be to use `namedtuple` here. For this, lists of names, functions and their arguments are created, then functions applied and results joined with the attribute names:

```
from collections import namedtuple

def calc(n):
    return n * 2

n_list = [5, 10, 15]
names = [f"set_property_{n}" for n in n_list]

funcs = [calc] * 3
args = [(n,) for n in n_list]

result = [f(*a) for f, a in zip(funcs, args)]

A = namedtuple("A", names)

a = A._make(result)

print(a)
```

Output:

```
A(set_property_5=10, set_property_10=20, set_property_15=30)
```

Comment: Thx for answering! Can I ask a follow up question in regard to whether I should follow this approach?

I want to collect many attributes in my class and write them to a database when the calculations are done. Let's exaggerate and say I have 100 calculations/attributes that I have to define. Most of them follow the same structure where many of the same calculations are made with different parameters. 

Would you define them all manually? Or are there any other techniques I can look into?

Comment: @KevinvanderGugten I have updated my answer but I don't know your requirements good enough to know if this is a viable approach. If this is not suitable, you better ask a new question with more details.